# How to write text on image from form input in Laravel using intervention

Tags: php, laravel, intervention

I want to create image with text using Intervention from input form,how Do I do that here is my controller

```
public function store(Request $request)


        if($request->hasFile('content'))
        {
          $filenameWithExt = $request->file('content')->getClientOriginalName();
          $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt,PATHINFO_FILENAME);
          $extension = $request->file('content')->getClientOriginalExtension();
          $fileNameToStore = $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
          $path = $request->file('content')->storeAs('public/content',$fileNameToStore);
        }
        else
        {
            $fileNameToStore = 'No Image,Music and Video selected please! check and try again.';
        }

        $post = new Post;
        $post->title = $request->input('title');
        $post->body = $request->input('body');
        $post->subcategory_id = implode(',',$request->input('subcategory_id') );
        $post->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
        $post->content = $fileNameToStore;
        $post->save();

    }
```

Comment: http://image.intervention.io/api/text

Comment: How because I had tried without any achievement please if you could led up to there  where I am stacking I will be glad.

Answer (score 0):

```
$image = Input::file('image');

// Define File Name and Path
$filename  = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
$path = ('image/path/' . $filename);

// create Image from Input
$img = Image::make($image->getRealPath());

// write text
$img->text('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.');

// write text at position x , y 
$img->text('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.', 120, 100);

// use callback to define details
$img->text('foo', 0, 0, function($font) {
    $font->file('foo/bar.ttf');
    $font->size(24);
    $font->color('#fdf6e3');
    $font->align('center');
    $font->valign('top');
    $font->angle(45);
});

// draw transparent text
$img->text('foo', 0, 0, function($font) {
    $font->color(array(255, 255, 255, 0.5));
});

// Save Image to Path 
$img->text($path);
```

**REFERENCE:**
http://image.intervention.io/api/text

Answer (score 0):

```
$image = Input::file('image');

// Define File Name and Path
$filename  = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
$path = ('image/path/' . $filename);

// create Image from Input
$img = Image::make($image->getRealPath());

// write text
$img->text('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.');

// write text at position x , y 
$img->text('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.', 120, 100);

// use callback to define details
$img->text('foo', 0, 0, function($font) {
    $font->file('foo/bar.ttf');
    $font->size(24);
    $font->color('#fdf6e3');
    $font->align('center');
    $font->valign('top');
    $font->angle(45);
});

// draw transparent text
$img->text('foo', 0, 0, function($font) {
    $font->color(array(255, 255, 255, 0.5));
});

// Save Image to Path

$img->save($path);
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion